# How to set QDoubleSpinBox to Scientific Notation?

Tags: c++, qt

`QDoubleSpinBox` shows the number using decimal point by default

[image: number in decimal point notation]

and I'm trying to format it to scientific notation

[image: number in scientific notation]

My solution was to subclass `QDoubleSpinBox` and redefine methods `validate`, `valueFromText` and `textFromValue`.

```
class SciNotDoubleSpinbox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SciNotDoubleSpinbox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent) {}

    // Change the way we read the user input
    double valueFromText(const QString & text) const
    {
        double numFromStr = text.toDouble();
        return numFromStr;
    }

    // Change the way we show the internal number
    QString textFromValue(double value) const
    {
        return QString::number(value, 'E', 6);
    }

    // Change the way we validate user input (if validate => valueFromText)
    QValidator::State validate(QString &text, int&) const
    {

        // Try to convert the string to double
        bool ok;
        text.toDouble(&ok);
        // See if it's a valid Double
        QValidator::State validationState;
        if(ok)
        {
            // If string conversion was valid, set as ascceptable
            validationState = QValidator::Acceptable;

        }
        else
        {
            // If string conversion was invalid, set as invalid
            validationState = QValidator::Invalid;
        }
        return validationState;
    }
};
```

It works, but `validate` seems sloppy. It tries to convert the number to double using Qt's `toDouble`, and returns valid or invalid state depending if it was a successful conversion or not. It doesn't even use the position.

Is there a way to validate a string in scientific notation in a "cleaner" way?

Comment: Have you seen [this old discussion](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17318-qdoublespinbox-with-scientific-notation)?  It suggests to me (based on superficial skimming!) your solution is cleaner than you think, or that your solution doesn't account for all scenarios.

Comment: @eclarkso, yes. I used that solution as inspiration but it reimplements too many things.

Comment: Per your original question, I would initialize `ok` to `true` or `false`, and you can shorten the last section to `return ok ? QValidator::Acceptable : QValidator::Invalid;`.  But whether that's actually *correct* (or the old discussion does too many things)  depends on your goals/needs.  I suspect it's all the edge cases (including UI/usability) w/r/t editing the text in the spin box directly that drive all the code in the old discussion and in the regular `QDoubleSpinBox`, and I suspect your version is some combination of too permissive, too restrictive, or both.